# How to check the lambda function enviroment is being encrypted in transit or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to find a way to check if environment variables in lambda are being encrypted, using boto3 library in Python. I have tried a lot but haven't found the right solution yet :(

I haven't found a suitable solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Using the lambda client, you need to get the configuration of the lambda function.

```
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

response = lambda_client.get_function_configuration(FunctionName='function_name')
environment_variables = response['Environment']['Variables']
```

The value of the environmental variable will be prefixed with `aws:kms`

```
for key, value in environment_variables.items():
    if key == 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY':
        is_encrypted = value.startswith('aws:kms')
        break
```

The `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` is a good start, because that is guaranteed to be encrypted.

Comment: Thank for answer. However, i want to check all environment variables in a lamda function are being encrypted

Comment: You can simply use the sample code I provided, instead of using `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, you simply do the `is_encrypted` check and simply log 
```
print(f"{key} is encrypted? {is_encrypted}")
```